# Should I use Dreamweaver's Spry?

Tags: dreamweaver, spry

I was Dreamweaving a bit and saw something called Spry. Is this powerful or can I better use jQuery and code everything my own?

Spry also messes up my code when I add a menu.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spry Assets in dreamweaver is a great source. You can use it not a problem.

Advantages :

1) Works in all browsers(Browser Compatible)
2) Simple to implement
3) User friendly code and comments to assist you while editing
4) Optimized code

So i recommend you to use spry assets. If your requirement doesn't match with spry you can go for Jquery.